# Is it possible to open an Ubuntu app from HTML?

Tags: html

I'm creating a webpage right now and am wondering if it is possible to input a command in HTML that will open an installed Ubuntu app like Chromium, or a terminal window, or Nautilus.

Is something like this possible? Thanks!

Comment: In Windows it was, but only if you ran IExplorer, but due to the fact that a web page is text only with a bit of server side magic, this limits what a browser is capable of. I'm sure someone will come up with something. Java app may be?

Comment: You perhaps should clarify in what environment you are running since it is very broad at the moment.  For example - you could be running a html page within webkit-webview which could be connected to a python based app etc etc.

Comment: Hmmm... I assumed pure HTML @fossfreedom >:-D

Comment: Yes, this is just a basic HTML webpage. No databases or anything.

Comment: If its any help, the site will be for linux users. Anyone could use it naturally, but I'm designing this strictly for linux/Ubuntu users.

Seems simple enough. Launch an Ubuntu app like the terminal or calculator from a link on a webpage. For example if I do "apt://chromium-browser" it opens the Ubuntu Software Centers Chromium Page. So we know we can launch at least the USC from HTML. What about Ubuntu/linux apps?

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can by adding a new protocol handler in your Ubuntu. The following method will show you how to register the process of opening an application as `app://[application_name]` protocol handler in Ubuntu.

#### 1. Create application launcher script

- In a terminal run:

  ```
  mkdir -p bin
  ```

  This command will make a `bin` directory in your `home` folder if you don't already have it.
- After run:

  ```
  gedit ~/bin/open_app.sh
  ```

  This will create the new file `open_app.sh` in gedit.
- Copy and paste the following script in the new created file:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/bash

  if [[ "$1" != "app://" ]]; then 
      app=${1#app://}
      nohup "$app" &>/dev/null &
  else 
      nohup gnome-terminal &>/dev/null &
  fi
  ```
- Save the file and close it.
- Go back into terminal and run:

  ```
  chmod +x ~/bin/open_app.sh
  ```

  to grant execute access for the script.

#### 2. Create .desktop file for application launcher

Now you must create a .desktop launcher for the above script, and tell Ubuntu to use this launcher as `app://` protocol handler. Create `/usr/share/applications/appurl.desktop` file using the following command:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/appurl.desktop
```

and add the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TerminalURL
Exec=/home/radu/bin/open_app.sh %u
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
Categories=System;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/app;
```

Save the file and close it.

#### 3. Refresh mime types database

In the file above, the line `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/app;` register `app://` scheme handler, but to make it work we should update mime types database cache by executing command:

```
sudo update-desktop-database
```

#### 4. Test from terminal

Now everything should work. To test that it works from terminal, run for example this command:

```
xdg-open 'app://gedit'
```

#### 4. Test from browser using HTML

You can test from browser by using for example the following HTML web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Open some applications</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
        <h3>Open some applications in Ubuntu from HTML</h3>
        <p>Open terminal: <a title="Open" href="app://">app://</a>
        (equivalent with: <a title="Open" href="app://gnome-terminal">app://gnome-terminal</a>)</p>
        <p>Open Nautilus: <a title="Open" href="app://nautilus">app://nautilus</a></p>
        <p>Open Chromium: <a title="Open" href="app://chromium-browser">app://chromium-browser</a></p>
        <p>Open Ubuntu Software Center: <a title="Open" href="app://software-center">app://software-center</a>
        (equivalent with: <a title="Open" href="apt://">apt://</a>)</p>
        <p>...and so on</p>
</body>

</html>
```

The result:

[image: app://]

Comment: Very very nice. 1 slight problem: the users using the website will not have those scrips, launchers and mime types. So you also need to supply them in some manner from the website. With navigator.registerProtocolHandler it should be possible to do w/o installing software. But it does look very very nice :-D

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, a script that automate the steps 1, 2 and 3 can be provided to the users using the website before to use `app://` scheme handler. Using `exec()` function from PHP, for example, that script can be made to run in browser.

Comment: exec() will run server side, not client side. If you try client side, you will find browsers security will prevent the scripts running

Comment: Cool! Remember to change `radu` to your name in `appurl.desktop`. As like: `Exec=/home/{YOUR NAME HERE}/bin/open_app.sh %u`

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Is it possible to launch an script instead of an app? For example `app://shell-exec myscript.sh` where shell-exec is just an another script (`#!/bin/sh
"$@"
exec "$SHELL"`)

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to pass params to the local app?

Comment: not working at all for ubuntu 20.0

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is called "Web-based protocol handlers". You need Chrome 13 or Firefox 3.0 or higher. I have seen it used to open LibreOffice.

Both [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers) and [updates.html5rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler) have an explanation about how this works. (Open in Chrome/Chromium `chrome://settings/handlers` and it will show a list of current handlers. Firefox will list them in `about:config`.)

Parts from the 1st link:

**Registering**

Setting up a web application as a protocol handler is not a difficult process. Basically, the web application uses registerProtocolHandler() to register itself with the browser as a potential handler for a given protocol. For example:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",
                              "https://www.example.com/?uri=%s",
                              "Example Mail");
```

Where the parameters are:

- The protocol.
- The URL template, used as the handler. The "%s" is replaced with the href of the link and a GET is executed on the resultant URL.
- The user friendly name for the protocol handler.

When a browser executes this code, it should display a prompt to the user, asking permission to allow the web application to register as a handler for the protocol. Firefox displays a prompt in the notification bar area.

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Web Protocol Handler Sample - Register</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("fake", "http://starkravingfinkle.org/projects/wph/handler.php?value=%s", "Fake Protocol");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Web Protocol Handler Sample</h1>
    <p>This web page will install a web protocol handler for the <code>fake:</code> protocol.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to pass params to the local app?

Comment: This seems to allow apps like a webmailer, but no external (local) applications.

Comment: Read the details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler/Web-based_protocol_handlers). Also, [on the first link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler#Permitted_schemes), you'll also see that the `scheme` is restricted to only a few. The accepted solution will deliver a better resolution (of course with some tweaks as needed).

Comment: For the curious, refer to [W3 consortium specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#custom-handlers)