# pass arguments which has spaces to new protocol

Tags: nautilus, scripts, html

I have created new protocol handler for opening application through web pages where a link will open installed application like terminal/chrome etc as suggested in: ([Is it possible to open an Ubuntu app from HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330937/is-it-possible-to-open-an-ubuntu-app-from-html/332389#332389)) , in my case its nautilus file browser.. worked perfectly w/o any arguments, however when I pass arguments like  'app://nautilus /home/user/dir/my dir/' (argument has space in it, it fails even tried escape sequence ('\') for space, no luck.

Here, I am trying to open directories in random sequence where I cannot create symbolic link for each of directories. Can some one help me how to pass arguments which has spaces  to new created protocol ?

any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

tried creating a shell script test.sh which has just nautilus $@ , and nautilus "$@" and ran test.sh "/home/usr/dir/my\ dir" and all above combination, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to put that part in between "'s.  So that would be

```
"app://nautilus /home/user/dir/my dir/"
```

That is a common method when dealing with spaces and parameters.

Alternative: html uses url encoding. A space would then become a `%20`:

```
app://nautilus%20/home/user/dir/my%20dir/
```

Comment: I tried many combination "app://nautilus /home/user/dir/my dir/" "app://nautilus /home/user/dir/my\ dir/" "app://nautilus" /home/user/dir/my dir/ app://nautilus /home/user/dir/my dir/, it just treat as different path/directory

Comment: Maybe worth a shot: try `%20` as a space :) If those 2 do not work I would consider filing a bug.

Comment: yeah tried, %20, single colon around whole, '\' before space, "app://nautilus\ /home/user/dir/my\ dir/", "app://nautilus /home/user/dir/my%20dir/", app://nautilus "/home/user/dir/my%20dir/" no luck. may not be bug I believe some where something goofed up - well symbolic links to those folders (which has space in it) works perfectly which is not an option for me :(

Comment: app://nautilus%20/home/user/dir/my%20dir/  whole will be treated as  application and returns command not found from xdg-open

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind, I found solution, its the argument in which we were passing to protocol handler. small modification in shell script, we need to put "'s in protocol handler rather in php/html and removed all escape chars since we are using "'s.