# Is it possible to open an Ubuntu app from HTML in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, html

[Is it possible to open an Ubuntu app from HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330937/is-it-possible-to-open-an-ubuntu-app-from-html)

https://askubuntu.com/a/332389/447970

The given solution is working fine in Chrome and Chromium browsers, but not in Firefox. Is there any setting changes in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out a solution, its a network.protocol-handler issue. Added an entry in firefox config. as:

```
network.protocol-handler.external.app;true
```

now its working fine.

thanks for the support
- Jay