# How to open an external application or launcher from within the browser?

Tags: google-chrome

In mobile applications, I guess this is called "deep linking". I want similar on the desktop via Chrome browser. For example, when I click a Zoom meeting link, the browser asks me to open it on the Zoom application installed on my Ubuntu.

I want to create bookmarks that open applications like VS Code etc.

Applications do use `xdg-open` to open a URL on the preferred browser. I need some way I can do the reverse. Something like triggering a `.desktop` launcher file from within the Chrome browser. Any way like how Zoom does it.

Comment: May be related to this question? [Is it possible to open an Ubuntu app from HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330937/is-it-possible-to-open-an-ubuntu-app-from-html)

Comment: Thanks @FedKad, that's exactly what I was looking for.